# State list drawable for textview

Tags: java, android, text, drawable

I just want to put a text, for example in blue, and when i press it to turn in another color.
But not like setTextColor(int) but more like a link, that's why i why thinking about state list drawable. Do you know how can i implement this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use colors instead of drawables for that.
Use some thing like this:

file: res/color/state_white_blue.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="@color/text_white" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="@color/text_white" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:color="@color/text_white" />
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:color="@color/text_white" />
    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:color="@color/text_white" />
    <item
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_checked="false"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:color="@color/text_blue" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Did you used value or color list. Because when i use Color list, i can't put items.